# Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘UsingR’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r

install.packages('UsingR', dependecies = TRUE)

This is my command in the console, and it keeps displaying the error message indicating a non-zero exit code. What is the solution?

Comment: Scroll up and try to find the message, which dependency failed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.